# ngRepeat with $scope.$apply creates duplicates in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, coffeescript, qtip2

I have a directive that puts dynamic data into a qTip via a template. It does so by fetching the template and using `$compile` on it (excuse the coffeescript):

```
$http.get scope.qtipTemplate, cache: $templateCache
.then (html) ->
  clone = $compile html.data
  generateQtip text: ->
    scope.$apply ->
      clone scope
```

The `generateQtip` simply creates a new qTip on the directive element and puts the first argument as the `content` property on the options object.

What happens though is, every time I open the qTip, the `ngRepeat` in the template produces duplicate lists, even with `limitTo` as a filter. Example code:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in object.people | limitTo:3 track by $index">{{person.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Produces the following the **first** time I open the qTip:

> - John Doe
> - Jane Doe
> - Johnny Dowy

And this on the **second** time:

> - John Doe
> - Jane Doe
> - Johnny Dowy
> - John Doe
> - Jane Doe
> - Johnny Dowy

And this on the **third** time:

> - John Doe
> - Jane Doe
> - Johnny Dowy
> - John Doe
> - Jane Doe
> - Johnny Dowy
> - John Doe
> - Jane Doe
> - Johnny Dowy

And so on, and so on.

Why does this happen? Any ideas? Here's my full directive code in [this link](https://gist.github.com/sxasraf/85fe573756420385b906).

Comment: do you mind providing the correct link to your complete directive code?

Comment: I would also post: (function () {
    $http.get(scope.qtipTemplate, { cache: $templateCache }).then(function (html) {
        var clone;
        clone = $compile(html.data);
        return generateQtip({
            text: function () {
                return scope.$apply(function () {
                    return clone(scope);
                });
            }
        });
    });
}.call(this)); as your code instead of using the coffee script as not as many people know how to read or write coffee script. Also your directive code link is broken.

Comment: Dumb question, but since the link to the complete code doesn't work and I'm far from a Coffee expert, are you clearing the array before assigning back to it?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the link. @tuckerjt07 which array? No, I'm assigning the scope. Anyways, I solved this, I'll post the answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but I simply had to move the `$compile` further inside.

```
$http.get scope.qtipTemplate, cache: $templateCache
.then (html) ->
  generateQtip text: ->
    scope.$apply ->
      $compile(html.data)(scope)
```